# Sparklyr - Can connect to cluster, but can not query it

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am able to connect to spark just fine 

`library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", spark_home = "/usr/lib/spark2")`

And I can see all the tables in the `default` database in the connections window of Rstudio, however, all my commands fail with an error along the lines of `Failed to get broadcast_0_piece0 of broadcast_0`.

Note that I can run commands like `tbl(sc, "tblname") %>% colnames`. Anything involving data manipulation will not run, such as `tbl(sc, "tblname") %>% sample_n(20)`.

Any ideas on how I could debug this?

Here is the code I was trying to run:

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", spark_home = "/usr/lib/spark", version = 1.6)
t <- tbl(sc, "tbl_name")  
t %>% sample_n(20) %>% head
```

Here is the error showing up in the spark log

```
18/04/20 17:38:28 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
18/04/20 17:38:28 ERROR sparklyr: Backend (24866) failed calling collect on sparklyr.Utils
```

Here is the complete log:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, bigdataworker11.host.bo1.csnzoo.com, executor 1): java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_2_piece0 of broadcast_2
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1214)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:242)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_2_piece0 of broadcast_2
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:140)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:121)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1207)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you share the complete log? there might be a case wherein multiple spark contexts are getting initialized leading to this error. Please share your complete log and code as well.

Comment: @ShrinivasDeshmukh Added the log!

Comment: You are running it via yarn right? Is this the yarn log file? It seems it is not. Please go to your job from yarn web ui and you can find log there. Stderr is the error log